# I have a Linux box. How do I see how my HTML pages look as rendered in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, browser

I have a Linux box. How do I see how my [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) pages look as rendered in Microsoft Internet Explorer? How do I test [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) functionality in Internet Explorer?

I don't want to install a [VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) and a copy of the Windows OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best friend as a Linux web developer is [IEs4Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEs4Linux), which uses [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) to run different versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 8):

Check out this page to see how your page will look across browsers and OS'

http://browsershots.org/

To actually interact with your web site though I would suggest something like [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) or a VM like [Xen](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/srg/netos/xen/).

Also see this link: [How to install internet explorer on Ubuntu](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_internet_explorer) or see this page [IEs4Linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page).

Comment: Doesn't wine use Gecko, rather than reimplementing IE?

Comment: You can run windows programs on Wine including IE.

Comment: If you run IE under Wine, then you are using IE, not Gecko.

Answer (score 3):

I use Linux at work and do web development that has to support Internet Explorer 6 (and later) and Firefox 2 (and later).

[IE4Linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page) is not really good enough for properly testing Internet Explorer browser rendering as it doesn't work exactly as Internet Explorer does in Windows. You could use something like [browsershots](http://browsershots.org), but I would recommend running Windows in a VM and test using that for Internet Explorer testing. I've done that for awhile and it works great as long as you have a spare 512 MB RAM for Windows XP.

Comment: Great suggestion, but my primary box these days is a netbook. Spare ram I do not have.

Comment: ouch, then I dunno dude. I've tried using IE4Linux before but I've had incorrect CSS, CTDs (from JS no lesS) and various rendering issues with it before. It might be good enough for a base santiy check with more detailed checks on XP done only so often.

Answer (score 1):

Another service similiar to browsershots, but faster, is [IE NetRenderer](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/). Otherwise, if you have a copy of Windows lying around, why not use a virtual machine? Suns [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) is nice enough.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that `browsershots.org` is a great place to start, but it only provides a screenshot. If you're using [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) or [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and need to see how see how things appear when you interact with your page in Internet Explorer (practically any version from Internet Explorer 5 and up), `crossbrowsertesting.com` is an excellent resource.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet for accurate rendering without paying for a Windows license is using one of the MS provided virtual machines. Below are some links on tutorials for setting up the VMs using VirtualBox.

http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2009/03/internet-explorer-application-compatibility-vpc-images-under-virtualbox/

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/installing-windows-7-on-a-virtual-machine/

I've used VirtualBox and these images quite a bit and it works well, the only downside is you have to reinstall every quarter because the images expire.